# Как парсить картинку из ленты rss?

Tags: xml, android, sax, парсер

xml-парсером парсю rss-ленту вида `http://gazetaingush....id=2&format=raw`. 
В ленте есть в новостях картинки, они в приложении не отображаются. ((( 
Сам пример брал с сайта:
http://anddev.ru/42/...nktsionala.html

Comment: Попробовали бы сами для начала открыть свои ссылки.

Comment: за ссылки изиняюсь

Comment: http://gazetaingush.ru/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=4&format=raw
такона добавилась обычная ссылка из rss  ленты в теге <description> где идет полный текст новости есть картинка вида

Comment: <div align="justify"><img class="caption" src="http://gazetaingush.ru/images/stories/2014/161/161-1.gif" border="0" hspace="10" vspace="10" width="150" height="100" align="left" />

Comment: вот эта картинка в приложении не хочет отображаться я новичок в этом деле не судите строго

Answer (score 2):

Может потому, что нужно не просто парсером ссылку получть, но и саму картинку по этой ссылке подгрузить?)Например с помощь Universal Image Loader

Comment: Спасибо большое пол интернета перерыл не где не че не нашол щас буду гуглит 
Universal Image Loader а как его релизавать ? я в этом новичек

Comment: нашол  урок  по этому 
http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/5-universal-image-loader-part-2.html

Comment: http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/6-universal-image-loader-part-3-usage.html
уж больно все сложно а проще метода нет ? в приложении вместо картинки отображается маленький синий квадратик

Comment: Как бы ссылку на уроки я Вам дал) качаете библиотеку и http://hashcode.ru/questions/366002/java-universal-image-loader-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-url-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-json тут обсуждалось как её использовать, если ничего не понятно)

Comment: ну у меня же не jason parser а xml sax parser 
нужно что бы картинка выводилась в том месте где она в посте выводится